# Contact form submission type in Contact Form Extensions

Tags: form, plugin-contactform, plugin-contactformextensions

I have a site with three forms that use P&Ts Contact Form plugin. My client now wants the submissions to be visible in the backend and have a 'download to CSV' if possible.

I was looking into the Contact Form Extensions plugin to visualise the data, but I can't find a way to change the submission type from 'contact' so the three different form types can be easily filtered in the left hand column (see screen below).

[image]

Is there a way to do this with some custom code on submission? Also, is there a plugin to allow me to download the submissions as CSV?

I'm basically just trying to avoid a new form plugin entirely as the forms are built quite custom on the front end.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the form name by adding a hidden field to your form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="message[formName]" value="myFormName">
```

Set the `value` of the hidden field to a unique value for each different form that you have on the site. Then submissions to each form will then be indexed in the control panel by the different values used for the hidden field.

Full documentation for the Contact Form Extensions plugin can be found here: https://github.com/hybridinteractive/craft-contact-form-extensions/blob/master/README.md

There's currently no native way to export the submissions to a CSV. There is a GitHub issue open for this (https://github.com/hybridinteractive/craft-contact-form-extensions/issues/13) which includes a suggested work around using a Twig template to handle the exports: https://github.com/hybridinteractive/craft-contact-form-extensions/issues/13#issuecomment-518668747

Comment: Oh wow, how did I miss that on the docs. I’m banging my head against the desk ‍♂️ 

Thanks so much for the reply. The CSV workaround is proving a success too.


You may have just saved me a lot of work, thank you Steve!